# WHM/CPanel system applying a per-user MySQL resource limit

Tags: linux, mysql, web-server

Through testing of our server, I have come to the conclusion that our server is somehow limiting usage per user to MySQL.

When I run mysqltuner.pl, the script pegs one of the processors for several minutes at a time. While this script is running (from Account X), Account X slows to a crawl. Requests to X's web assets are extremely slow. However, requests to other accounts' web assets (i.e. Accounts Y and Z) run quickly and mostly without delay.

Is it possible that there are some limiting mechanisms in place that are enforced via MySQL, CPanel, or some third-party tool?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can limit individual user accounts by:

- Number of queries per hour
- Number of updates per hour
- Number of new connections per hour
- Number of simultaneous connections

Given your description, it seems most likely it's #4 that's giving you trouble.  Some long running query is blocking part of your connection pool.

Try this out:

```
 SELECT max_connections
 FROM mysql.user
 WHERE user = 'Account X';
```

MySQL's documentation on per user account limits is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html).